# W5500 with a PIC18F

Tags: tcp, pic, modbus, microchip

Is there a PIC18F/PIC24F port of the W5500 hardware TCP/IP stack where the existing Microchip TCP/IP (and/or Lite) functions. Idea is to replace ENC24J60 in existing with W5500 from Wiznet and free up memory and processing to add functions. I tried following the W5200 guide but doesn't seem to work. I can't find examples also.
Any help or pointer would be great.
Thank you for your time.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

At wiznet there is are some files you can add to Microchips MLA stack for W5200.  Fixing that for W5500 is not entirely trivial, but not extremely hard either. (cost me about two days)

They are not terribly efficient though, as no MLA driver (ENC* or W5x00) seems to utilize DMA

Comment: Thanks Marco van de Voort for your answer. There was actually a board based on W5200 for PICDEM and Explorer but Microchip no more supports it. I tried downloading MLA dating back to 2013 still no Joy. My intention is to be able to use the Microchip Foundation Services Drives alongwith the W5500. So I was thinking if I could just replace the software stack into hardware having similar function calls

Comment: That pictail board for pic24ga explorer16 was my starting point. You needed MLA _AND_ a set of files by microchip. I cut out everything but UDP, and then migrated to dspic33e with W5500 and introduced DMA. The code is my employers, but got permission to publish a flow chart : https://forum.wiznet.io/t/topic/4539 We are now sampling the first production boards.

Comment: thank you for the flowchart. It will be a great starting point. Much appreciated. Thanks again